# Why have a “integer expression expected”?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why I have a integer expression expected error with this:

```
at=`echo $1 | grep -q "@"`
if [ $at -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "blabla"
else
    echo "bloblo"
fi
```

`$at` is set, and the test working fine outside the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When testing the result of `grep -q`, you want to test `$?` not the output of grep, which will be empty

```
at=$(echo "$1" | grep -q "@")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...
```

or simply

```
if echo "$1" | grep -q "@"; then ...
```

or, more bash-ly

```
if grep -q "@" <<< "$1"; then ...
```

or, without calling grep:

```
if [[ "$1" == *@* ]]; then ...
```

or

```
case "$1" in
  *@*) echo "match" ;;
  *) echo "no match" ;;
esac
```

Comment: When testing the result of grep -q, you want to test $? : EXACTLY Thanks for all the way you purpose, I think I learn something today :) particulary like the "no grep" syntax. And thanks by the way

Answer (score 3):

`-ne` is for comparing integers. Use `!=` to compare strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! it's working fine, but it needed [ "$at" != 0 ]; Thanks for the very quick reply :) –